# Vertex texture painting does not work because of scale

Tags: transforms, texture-painting, vertex-paint, texture-paint-mode, vertex-paint-mode

When I want to vertex texture paint I can't paint anything. I can paint other objects in the same scene until I scale an object. Apply scale does also not work. I just want a simple vertex texture paint on a plane :'(

Comment: can you add a simple blend file that shows the problem? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: I’ve noticed a problem with texture painting that seems to have the brush lining up in the wrong place. This might be a bug…